# Client app calling Stripe API after card form exit, for future payment

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, strong-customer-authentication

I am adding Stripe 3D secure to a React-Native app, following the document at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse
-- save the card, and charge off-session later when the service is completed.

For saving card, my app uses a WebView component to load a HTML, using `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` .
It successfully saved the client secret and exited the card form.

Question:  At payment time later, in case next action for strong customer authentication is required, how to get a stripe object again so as to call `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`?

I tried below but failed -- catch(error), and error is empty.

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

confirmPayment = async () => {
  try {
    const stripe = await loadStripe("pk_test_...");

//    stripe
//       .confirmPaymentIntent('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
//           payment_method: '{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}',
//           return_url: 'https://example.com/return_url',
//       })
//       .then(function(result) {
//
//       });

  } catch(error) {
    console.error(`failed to load stripe ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stripe.confirmCardPayment` in a variety of ways. In your case you probably already have a PaymentMethod ID, meaning you can [confirm the PaymentIntent client side with that PaymentMethod ID](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-existing) instead of an Elements object:

```
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: '{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}',
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

Comment: How do I get a stripe object?   Thanks.

Comment: You would have to include and initialize Stripe.js on your page: https://stripe.com/docs/js/initializing